# How to control method response by server in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

We have made ajax call through angular js and expecting output according to operation.

### Following are the operation:  Add and Remove

On click on Add: if operation successful; it shows message "Row Added Successfully"

On click on Remove: if operation successful; it shows message "Row Removed Successfully"

```
And, message display on client browser in a div with jquery fadeIn, fadeOut effect.
```

### Problem Faced at particular case: -

But there is a case in which, I am continuously hitting on add button; which should display "Row Added Successfully" message, but sudden, if I click on remove button; it converts my all message to "Row Removed Successfully"

```
And, loop go continuously according to number of times, I hit on buttons.
```

Comment: You need to post your code in your question otherwise it is very difficult to help

Comment: Answer to this entirely depends on the context of your code. We need to see mark-up and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try separate variables to hold the

```
  Row Removed Successfully/Row Removed Successfully
```

messages. Which can solve the problem easily.